# Looking for 80's sci-fi book with teens with metal letters/numbers embedded in their heads

Tags: story-identification, books

- It might be a YA sci-fi book.
- The teens had metal letters/numbers embedded in their heads and might be gang members.
- There might be a prison on the moon.
- I know it was published before 1987. I read it at the Morley Public Library in Painesville, Ohio in 1986. It was written in English.

Comment: This question is very terse and could be vastly improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Can you contact the library and ask them what books you got out in 1986? The library is still there and may well still have your records.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible '[Exiles of Colsec](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/597106.Exiles_of_Colsec)' and sequels by Douglas Hill. Two of the protagonists (Jeko and Rontal) are gang members with a metal 'S' on the forehead and their initials raised scars on their heads.

In the last novel, they escape from a prison and fight a battle within an asteroid mine.

Comment: This looks like a good possibility! I'm going to try to find it and figure it out thank you so much!

Comment: The'Exiles of Colsec' and sequels by Douglas Hill IS the correct answer although I remembered much of this book wrong. Regardless, THANK YOU VERY MUCH!